# The below code wont execute with some inputs

Tags: java

Sorry for such a basic level question guys. But I'm starter in programming. Not a computers guy. So kindly help me. 
In this code when I give input `1000000000`, `1000000000`, `999999999` the answer should be 4. But my answer is 1. I expect the `if` statement to execute but it is not executing here.

if you take m*n as a room and "a" as the side as a square tile. Then I want to count MINIMUM no. of tiles required to fill the floor of room. tiles may cover a bit more area but should not leave the room empty. this is my objective. It's working with inputs like 6,6,4 or 15,20,13 etc.

**Now its working guys. I had posted the correct code with those minor changes below.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TheatreSquare {
    private static Scanner input;
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     input = new Scanner(System.in);
     float m=input.nextFloat();
     float n=input.nextFloat();
     float a=input.nextFloat();
     long i=(int)(m/a);
     long j=(int)(n/a);

     if((a*a*i*j)<m*n){

        if(a*i<m){
            //to check weather it is entering if()
            System.out.println("true");
            i+=1;
        }
        if(a*j<n){
            System.out.println("false");
            //to check weather it is entering if()
            j+=1;
        }
       }
       System.out.println((double)(i*j));
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'd suspect it's something in this line: `long i=(int)(m/a);` or next line `long j=(int)(n/a);`. When you divide like that you loose precision.

Comment: Please explain exactly what your program is supposed to do. It's hard to guess - especially when the variable names are meaningless. You should name the variables according to what they do. Please edit your question and add the necessary information.

Comment: Can you explain what is the end goal of this piece of code? What do you want to achieve? You have a lot of odd casting (from float to int to long to double), it's hard to tell if they make sense without knowing the idea behind them

Comment: Did you try to debug your program and check why it behaves the way it should?

Comment: if you take m*n as a room and "a" as the side as a square tile. Then I want to count minimum no. of tiles required to fill the room. tiles may cover more area but should not leave the room empty. this is my objective. It's working with inputs like 6,6,4 or 15,20,13 etc.

Comment: I really used odd casting but I felt it is useful because a tile cannot be counted in decimals. so i used int. And I used long because the room size can be soo large. @DiegoMartinoia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your floats are overflowing when you multiply them. Defining `m`, `n` and `a` as `double`s will solve the issue:

```
double m = input.nextDouble();
double n = input.nextDouble();
double a = input.nextDouble();
```

Comment: You are correct partially. When I used double it worked. Thank you for the clue. But can you explain me this why it didn't worked for float(overflowing means??)

Answer (score 2):

The int conversion loses precision.

Here in this case, `a*a*i*j` is equal to `m*n` Hence the if loop will not execute. Also `a*i` is equal to `m` and `a*j` is equal to n. 
Hence i isi and j is 1, so `i*j` is 1.
[image: Look at this]

You need to allow it to go if it is equal too.
Replace

```
if((a*a*i*j)<m*n){

        if(a*i<m){
            //to check weather it is entering if()
            System.out.println("true");
            i+=1;
        }
        if(a*j<n){
            System.out.println("false");
            //to check weather it is entering if()
            j+=1;
        }
       }
```

**with**

```
if((a*a*i*j) <= m*n){
        System.out.println("Entered if block");
        if(a*i <= m){
            //to check weather it is entering if()
            System.out.println("true");
            i+=1;
        }
        if(a*j <= n ){
            System.out.println("false");
            //to check weather it is entering if()
            j+=1;
        }
        System.out.println("i is:"+ i +"j is:"+j);
       }
```

Comment: m*n is float but in the other case it is int. you can try it with other inputs such as 1000000000 1000000000 192 or 6 8 4 or 6 6 4 or any other small integers. if loop is executing here.

Comment: @Krishna I'm thinking you need to let the loop execute even if the condition stays equal

Comment: Right now, this problem solved. But ans is not correct for input 1,1,1. Ans should be one. because both the room size and tile size is same. there should be only one tile in it. but the output is 4. Thank you for the reply but it should be refined. @Uma Lakshmi Kanth

Answer (score 2):

thankyou @Mureinik, @Uma Lakshmi Kanth, @Diego Martinoia for helping to solve this. All your answers contributed to solve my question. this is working now. as @Mureinik said my floats are overflowing( though I dont know the meaning). I used Double instead of float and that's it. its working. :-)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TheatreSquare {
private static Scanner input;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double m=input.nextDouble();
    double n=input.nextDouble();
    double a=input.nextDouble();
    long i=(long)(m/a);
    long j=(long)(n/a);

    if((a*a*i*j) <m*n){
        if(a*i < m){
            //to check weather it is entering if()
            i+=1;
        }
        if(a*j < n ){
            //to check weather it is entering if()
            j+=1;
        }
       }
    System.out.println((long)(i*j));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your behavior is that you are reading numbers as floats. Floats have limited precision, so your m n and a are the same value (at runtime). Reading them as long (and getting rid of all the decimal stuff) should help. But, as mentioned in the comment, we don't know what you wanted to achieve!

--- EDIT DUE TO NEW INFO ---

You have to cover an area of m times n square meters. You have an unit of computation of 1 tile, i.e. a times a square meters (both assumed to be decimal).

Assuming you can cut your tile with good-enough precision, your result will be:

```
Math.ceiling((m*n) / (a*a));
```

i.e., either your area is an exact multiple of your tiles (and you can always cut them in rectangles to match the shape of the room), or you'll have some "spare" space to fill in, thus you will need 1 more tile, a part of which you'll use to cover the remaining space, and a part of which you'll throw away.

Comment: Sorry for that ambiguity. Now I have edited my question.

Comment: I added the answer to your real problem then :) see my edit up here